Can I Make the SLIDE RELAX Brush in Sculpt Mode Behave like the TWEAK Brush from RetopoFlow?
The Slide Relax brush in Sculpt Mode will reposition topological features without also changing any actual surface positions. This is handy, but would be handier if it worked the same way the Tweak brush works in RetopoFlow. The difference is that the Tweak brush only influences points that were originally under the brush cursor when you first clicked. The Slide Relax brush, in contrast, keeps influencing all points it encounters in the course of a brush stroke. This makes it difficult to make adjustments of only the points initially grabbed, since the stroke will bring every new point contacted by the brush along for the ride. There are settings for all brushes in Sculpt Mode, of course, but they don't appear to help me achieve this behavior. They appear to work based on the assumption that you will always want their effects applied to every point the brush stroke touches in the course of it being drawn. I don't.
